# Calling Methods from Enums

Tags: java

Is there anyway to call a method from an enum? For example:

```
public enum Skills {
     FIRE(callMethod());
}

public void callMethod(){
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Oh, you want to pass to the constructor a method (?) and call it?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, but _what should the method do_? I think what you want to achive cannot be achieved by calling the method. So, maybe it would help us to know what you want to do.

Comment: You could do this, but would be ugly and not what you want to do.. You could create a method inside the enum which is called and require the method(?)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a static method or a method of another class as a constructor argument to an enum constant, but be aware that static fields of enums are initialized at weird times as compared with other kinds of classes.

```
public enum Skills {
    FIRE(callMethod());
    private Skills( Object oIgnored ) {
    }
}

public static Object callMethod(){
     //do stuff
    return null;
}
```

or

```
public enum Skills {
    FIRE;
    private Skills() {
        callMethod();
    }
}

public static void callMethod(){
     //do stuff
}
```